# Грамматическая основа

Tags: грамматика

Объясните, пожалуйста, еще раз.   Какая основа в предложениях типа Бежать было трудно. Трудно бежать.  Бежать по жаре трудно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На этот счёт есть много разных мнений.Некоторые учёные предлагают проверить двусоставность наличием существования конструкции с творительным падежом:Бежать было делом трудным.-двусоставное.Значит,бежать-подлежащее, было трудно - сказуемое. Трудно бежать.-безличное однозначно. Бежать по жаре было делом трудным.-бежать-подл., было трудно - сказуемое.

Скобликова("Синтаксис простого предложения" -М., 1979.) считает все конструкции безличными.

Д.Э. Розенталь говорит, что при сказуемом, выраженном словами на-О, на 1 месте обычно стоит подлежащее,т.е. предложение с инфинитивом на 1 месте двусоставное, при обратном порядке слов предложение односоставное безличное. По Розенталю:Бежать(подлеж.) было трудно.(сказ.)Предлож. двусоставное. Трудно бежать-.безличное, всё сказуемое. Бежать (подлеж.)по жаре(обст.) трудно.(сказ.)Можно проверить конструкцией: Бежать - это каково?- трудно.-двусоставное.

В ЕГЭ придерживаются такого мнения. А Вы решайте сами, к какому мнению присоединиться.Вспомните: Жить-Родине служить. Здесь явно жить - подлежащее.

Comment: Да, мне Ваше мнение понятно и нравится. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, в первом предложении грамматической основой является все предложение: "бежать было трудно",  во втором - "трудно бежать", в третьем - "бежать трудно"

Comment: Спасибо. А среди предложений есть двусоставные?

Answer (score 1):

> Учиться - всегда пригодится
> Это предложение не безличное.

Двусоставных(даже неполных)здесь нет, т.к. нет действующего лица, действие происходит само по себе. Предложения безличные.

Comment: Действующего лица нет и в некоторых двусоставных. Учиться - всегда пригодится.